# How to easily install Google Chrome and Firefox on RHEL 5.4 (RedHat)?

Tags: rhel, firefox, chrome

I heard that it should be not that hard to install Google Chrome and the latest Firefox on RHEL 5.4.  (the OS our company support is only up to RHEL 5.4).  It probably requires some `make install` and will uses the C compiler.

Can somebody give a definite and tested answer?  (instead of some webpage that might not work or dated back to 2007).

Please also mention any required packages (probably yum packages) and how to install them.

Comment: Did you try the rpm from `http://google.com/chrome`?

Comment: yes, and I tried downloading all 4 of those packages and nothing happens after the download. (using Firefox 3)

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? Did you install the package and try running `google-chrome`?

Comment: The question is, how do you "install" the package?  I am a newbie in RHEL / Fedora

Answer (score 3):

Use Google's Chrome Yum repository.

Create a file `/etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo` with the following contents:

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

Now you can install `google-chrome-stable`, or if you feel like taking some risks, you can install `google-chrome-beta` or `google-chrome-unstable`.

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error:

http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64  /repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-2, 'Name or service not known')>  
Trying other mirror.  
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: google-chrome. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: @GraemePerrow Works for me (and everyone else). Check your computer's nameservers and general Internet connectivity.

Comment: Probably has something to do with my company's firewall and proxy settings and such. Thanks anyway

Comment: @GraemePerrow Yeah, that would do it. Make sure you've specified the company proxy server in your yum configuration. If you need further help, you should probably ask a new question, or contact your IT department.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded that package, run `rpm -ivh package_name.rpm`.
Or click System/Administration/AddRemove Software, use the GUI tool to search 'chrome' package.

Answer (score 0):

On adding my company proxy in vi /etc/yum.conf, i was able to install chrome
example:
proxy=http://proxysvr.yourdom.com:3128

Answer (score 0):

I followed a process which worked for me.

I am using Redhat 7.4, and I've been through a lot to uninstall and install chrome and firefox, got partially successful with chrome and this is what I tried.

In the Linux terminal

Go to the root by typing

```
su -
```

Then type

```
rpm -qa
```

then (ctrl+f) and search for the keywords "google" or " chrome" or "mozilla" or "firefox" to check whether they are present or not and if they are available, then uninstall (remove) them by the following command (If you want to remove them)

```
yum remove [Package Name]
```

this removes the application

Then **install chrome by the following process**

type this in terminal

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

then a package gets downloaded in your *current working directory*

Then type the following command - this installs the packages

```
yum -y install [Package You just Downloaded]
```

in this case it will be

```
yum -y install google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
```

This installs google chrome and creates an icon under `Application->Internet->googleChrome`

Important:

Technically, by clicking this googlechrome icon- this should open the browser, but it doesn't open the browser for me, I dont know whats the problem and I appreciate any suggestion regarding this issue.

I open google chrome through terminal using this command

```
google-chrome --no-sandbox
```

this opens the chrome browser.