# What is the best way to run a newer web browser (firefox, chrome, etc) on an older linux (rhel5)?

Tags: rhel, browser

What is the best way to run a newer web browser (firefox, chrome, etc) on an older linux (rhel5)?  RHEL5 only works with firefox up to about version 17, which is not sufficient for all web sites.  Assuming one cannot change the OS, but could install just about anything else, what is the best way to run a newer web browser?

The definition of Best is:  least performance impact to machine, most functionality of a native browser retained and simpliest maintenance.  For example, I could install VirtualBox and run Ubuntu and any browser I would like, but copy/paste from host to guest might be a problem and maintaining a separate Linux install would be somewhat painful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be running Firefox 45 ESR, not 17-ish. See <s>[RHSA-2016-0695](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2016-0695.html)</s> [RHSA-2016-1551](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2016-1551.html). That's rather critical, considering the number of security updates browsers get.

For Chrome, see [How to easily install Google Chrome and Firefox on RHEL 5.4 (RedHat)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61577/how-to-easily-install-google-chrome-and-firefox-on-rhel-5-4-redhat)

Comment: Both Firefox 45 and the Google Chrome as referenced by the above question have dependencies that RHEL5 cannot meet (e.g. libstdc++ is too old) and I can't mess with the versions of such important libraries.

Comment: @Jeff I'd expect if you grab the versions from the RedHat security advisory—which gives packages for RHEL 5—they should have dealt with all that (at least, if you've been keeping your system up-to-date with patches from them). [Appears there is actually a more recent advisory, use those packages instead.]

Comment: @Jeff see the instructions on https://access.redhat.com/articles/11258 to upgrade your RHEL5 installation, which will include Firefox 45 ESR.